# How to prevent a line break in a html link?

Tags: html, css

that is, a whole html link, must be in line1 or line 2. not in two lines.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

According to [this post](http://w3c-validation.blogspot.com/2008/11/nobr-tag-not-supported-by-w3c.html):

> NOBR Tag not suppored by W3C. So use the alternative tag for it.
>   Instead of giving NOBR tag give the tag as
>   style="white-space: nowrap".

So that would mean you should say:

```
<a style="white-space: nowrap">link</a>
```

Or even better, put it inside your CSS:

```
a { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Answer (score 10):

Using CSS:

```
a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This will prevent line breaks in any A tags.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<a><nobr>link</nobr></a>`

Please note: This will work but is not officially supported by the W3C spec.

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind it is not officially supported by the W3C spec.

Comment: @Justin Ethier, very good point I will add this to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

none of that worked for me.  I used a display:inline style and solved it

Answer (score 0):

By using '**text-decoration-line:none**' in your styling you can replace the pre made line below a link tag.
Here is the example of this

This will work

```
`<a href="your_link_here" style="text-decoration-line: none;">Home</a>`
```

or

you can also try this one if you are using external stylesheet:

```
a{text-decoration-line: none;}
```